# How To Create Something Similar To Cron Job For Android App

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How do I create something like cron job for my android app?

I want to create something like this for my app, for example:

I input data to room database. This data is a date, for example 15 September 2021. I want to create a task that compare date from database to date now. If it's the same, then do something (input another data to Room database for example).

How do I create a task that runs even though the app is not running or the app is killed?

I've followed this Codelabs https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-workmanager#0 but I think that is not something I'm looking for.

Is there any references I should look up to?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can look into periodic work manager to achieve this [link](https://medium.com/swlh/periodic-tasks-with-android-workmanager-c901dd9ba7bc)

Comment: I've followed the tutorial but I don't think it solves the question. https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-workmanager#0 shows everything about Work manager. As far as I understand, it can't do a future task. For example, today is 13 September 2021. And I wanna do a task tomorrow, or day after tomorrow. I tried Work manager, but when I kill the app and the scheduled date task comes, it just does nothing.

Comment: You can update your code with work manager so that we can look for the error as why it's not working.